# Notebook just freezes on boot process

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure

I've some trouble with my notebook, here are details:

Notebook: **ASUS Eee PC 1001PX**.

1. I used to think that the problem was with its hdd, but it's not. I've reinstalled OS through PC and it still doesn't work. On PC hdd works btw.
2. Then I realized that the problem can be related with bios and I can download [new BIOS](https://www.asus.com/support/Download/30/2/0/92/wxAfnQhtlL70yCov/29/) and reset it, but that option was wrong. [He simply stood at this stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkleJ.jpg).
3. And the last one, what do I want to do is just use 2 items (which I don't have) mean hot air gun for dismantling its bios, then insert it into programmer and firmware it through PC. What do you think, the game worth the candle?

Comment: So the bios is bricked now?

Comment: Actually idk, I guess, that he's still working but something went wrong with firmware. I can easy enter to the BIOS boot menu and setting up something. To be honest I've tried today some launches and for some reason one of it was successful, even with logging, but after 3 minutes it stood again.